# Как установить в базу данных Room данные из API?

Tags: android, rxjava, android-room, rxjava2

Нужно при запуске приложения получить данные от `Api` и добавить их в БД `Room`. Дальше список из БД должен отображаться в `RecyclerView`. Проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь добавить данные в БД с помощью `RxJava` я получаю ошибку, подскажите как исправить все?

Метод добавления данных в БД (DAO)

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM custom_table ORDER BY priority DESC")
    fun getAllContact(): List<Contact>
```

Установка данных в БД:

```
fun getAllContact(): List<Contact> {

        val disposable = CompositeDisposable()

        disposable.add(contactsRepository.modelSingle()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<List<Contact>>() {
                override fun onSuccess(t: List<Contact>) {
                allContacts = t
                }
                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                }
            }))

        return allContacts
    }
```

Ошибка:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

Comment: Вы пробовали переводить ошибку? Там же написана причина - запросы нужно деть не в основном потоке!

Comment: За перевод конечно спасибо, но проблема как раз в этом и заключается- в каких-бы потоках я не работал, все равно получаю данную ошибку

Comment: Ошибка, приведённая вами, насколько я вижу, не может возникнуть в вашем коде. А вот то, что у вас метод принципиально неправильно написан - явно видно. Т.к. у вас данные асинхронно получаются, вы не можете их из метода вернуть. Надо переписать код с учётом асинхронности, т.е. передавать данные на экран только когда они получены.

Comment: вообще room может работать с rxjava, поэтому можно сделать так `fun getAllContact(): Single<List<Contact>>` в Dao. но также исправьте то, что написал ЮрийСПб